# Android version 8.1 not display notification on status bar

Tags: android

Android version 8.1 not display notification on status bar when I used api level 26 and above but tone of notification hear and also receive notification. only the notification window is not visible even though is being received.

Comment: Can you explain more about it, for me your question is unclear

Comment: share your code to get some help

Comment: All android version below 26 show notification on status bar but in one device that has Oreo version notification ring hear but not showing on status bar.